# Append to list in R

Tags: r, list

This is basically what I´m trying to do:

```
##1.dataset
nn<-list()
nn[["i"]]<-data.frame(a=c(1,3,4,5,6),b=c(3,5,7,8,9),k=c("A"))
nn[["l"]]<-data.frame(a=c(3,4,5,2,1),b=c(9,2,3,5,6),k=c("B"))

##2.Average over list
u<-lapply(c("a","b"),function(x) rowMeans(sapply(nn, `[[`, x)))

##3.Append these results to each list
nn[["i"]]$mean_a<-u[[1]]
nn[["i"]]$mean_b<-u[[2]]
nn[["l"]]$mean_a<-u[[1]]
nn[["l"]]$mean_b<-u[[2]]
```

giving:

```
$i
  a b k mean_a mean_b
1 1 3 A    2.0    6.0
2 3 5 A    3.5    3.5
3 4 7 A    4.5    5.0
4 5 8 A    3.5    6.5
5 6 9 A    3.5    7.5

$l
  a b k mean_a mean_b
1 3 9 B    2.0    6.0
2 4 2 B    3.5    3.5
3 5 3 B    4.5    5.0
4 2 5 B    3.5    6.5
5 1 6 B    3.5    7.5
```

However, I assume there is a more clever way of doing step 2+3. At least it will be very tedious repeating this for 100 variables...

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want. Do you want rowMeans for a,b for each list?

Comment: you are just adding the same columns to each list element? `cols <- c('a','b'); lapply(nn, function(x) cbind(x, \`colnames<-\`(sapply(nn, function(y) rowMeans(y[, cols])), paste0('mean_', cols))))`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I haven´t seen the 'colnames<-' before. That was smart. Thx. If you submit as answer, I´ll accept it

Comment: If you use `lapply` instead of `sapply`, you can just use `setNames`, if you like.

Comment: What about `u2 <- as.data.frame(u, col.names = c("mean_a", "mean_b")); sapply(xx, FUN = function(x, y) cbind(x, y), y = u2, simplify = FALSE)`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a maybe easier to reason about method that uses the names attribute of the first argument in `lapply`:

```
v <- setNames(c("a","b"), paste0("mean_", c("a","b")))

lapply(nn, cbind, 
  data.frame(lapply(v, function(x) rowMeans(sapply(nn, "[[", x))))
)
```

Result:

```
$i
  a b k mean_a mean_b
1 1 3 A    2.0    6.0
2 3 5 A    3.5    3.5
3 4 7 A    4.5    5.0
4 5 8 A    3.5    6.5
5 6 9 A    3.5    7.5

$l
  a b k mean_a mean_b
1 3 9 B    2.0    6.0
2 4 2 B    3.5    3.5
3 5 3 B    4.5    5.0
4 2 5 B    3.5    6.5
5 1 6 B    3.5    7.5
```